# How to name an array that already has a plural name?

Tags: naming-conventions

What do you name your arrays when the name of the item is already plural?

`array names` makes sense.
`array collisionDatas` not so much.

Comment: Just a side-note. 'Data' is already plural...

Comment: @Nico: I believe the question refers more to "What name convention would I use for an array which stores multiple objects of type 'collisionData'?"

Comment: @Taylor Lion: Don't forget to accept the answer which you believe has answered your question!

Comment: @Ivan Vučica - I know :)  I was just being facetious.

Comment: Just a side-note: Neither of natural languages that I know has a word for an "array of arrays" or "list of lists" or "collection of sets" or anything like that. Perhaps natural languages don't have such words for a good reason. Perhaps it's a sign that "plural of plurals" is a design smell... Perhaps the class with plural noun as its name (the one whose instances you want to put into array) should be renamed and the problem will go away? ;)

Answer (score 3):

I almost always name it as `Item name + s`. My goal when naming a variable is to make sure that I reduce the effort needed to read and understand source code.

So if I have an array of `children` for example I name it `childrens`. I don't care at all if the `childrens` is an english word or not, I'm not writing a book! So later when a see something like:
`foreach (Object x in childrens)` I know I'm iterating on an array of children and not on an array of `child` objects.

Comment: @Ivan I would not call it wrong but I just don't prefer that.I  don't like it because it makes some variable names overly long.

Comment: Understood. Personally, I'm used to Cocoa and Objective-C nowadays, and over here such things are not unusual. For me, autocomplete is good enough, and the code ends up being quite readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your question heavily depends on the programming language. Objective-C has strong naming conventions that people adhere to.

Try `collisionDataArray`.

Personally, I'm used to Cocoa and Objective-C nowadays, and over here long variable and class names are not unusual. For me, autocomplete is good enough, and the code ends up being quite readable.

Answer (score -3):

I sometimes add the type in front, like:

```
array arrNames

array arrColisionData
```

I prefer to add the "arr" in the beginning so when you get them in an ordered list, they stay together.